# Should we choose XAML for UI desing in WP7 games?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

I am quite new to WP7 although have done lot of 2D games before(for BREW/J2ME).

But since in Windows phone we have the flexibility to create User Interface using XAML(through visual studio designer tools by drag/drop).

Is that really recommended or practical? I am asking because even the sample codes ([provided here](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/game_state_management)) doesn't have any XAML.

Comment: What do you mean by "drag/drop"? using visual studio designer or blend? at some point you're likely to have to put your hands in pure XAML if you want something clean.

Comment: thanks for prompting, edited my question. So I can I take it as "add/edit UI tools using VS-designer and change XAML for more complex structure"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on your comfortably. Windows Phone 7 application can be made using the following

- Silverlight for WP7 (Use this if your game is not very graphically intense)
- XNA for WP7 (use this if you want to create a REAL game)
- Silverlight and XNA for WP7 (use this if you would rather have all your menus using the easabilty of XAML, but still have all the gaming features XNA has)

Comment: Thanks, I would prefer 3rd way. But still is their any difference If I create my menu/UI using XAML(by drag/drop) or I create each tool like : Button playButton = new Button("Play");

Comment: Please do all your design work in XAML and NOT in the code behind.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft provided GamestateManagementExample (http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/game_state_management) provides an easy to use alternative to baking some Silverlight into your XNA game. You can customise various options and add/remove screens really simply. You can make it look much more proffesional than using some "sprite" buttons.